# Get the number of files in a directory using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I have created a symbolic link through the command `php artisan storage:link` and I store all the files stored by my users there. Every user has a folder with name of the folder as `md5($user_id)`. Then, I want to retrieve the files in my `blade` file. The problem is: my user can have multiple uploads so I need to get the number of files located in the directory. I searched the question and I found answers [linking to this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#directories) which has the solution that looks like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$files = Storage::files($directory);

$files = Storage::allFiles($directory);
```

, but the documentation is unclear. The `$directory` variable is not known and I don't know the root path of the method. So, what should my `$directory` variable contain so that I can include an image that is located in `myProject/public/storage/user_uploads/$name_of_the_folder`.

> And by the way, I get the `$name_of_the_folder` dynamically and the
>   `storage` folder in `public` is the symlink I have created with the
>   above command.

Comment: have you tried `count($files)` ??

Comment: Do you have a variable that links the target folder and the common path to reach it already?
Also, have you tried to use the `Storage::allFiles('path/to/your/target/dir');` ?
What outputs do you have for these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try adding in your **config/filesystems.php** file a `user_images` key:

```
'user_images' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path() . '/storage/',
],
```

After that, try in your code to access via `useR_images` by doing below:

```
Storage::allFiles('user_images');
```

From here, you can do any of their [tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem#basic-usage)

Comment: Great! That worked sweet. But, I didn't need to insert a new key. Instead, I changed the root of the method to `public_path()`.

Comment: @PHPCoder glad I could help! ^^